# female, male symbols no vector font with wasysym

Tags: fonts, symbols, embedding, wasysym

I need the `\female` and `\male` symbols in my document. However, by using the code below I only get pixel symbols in the pdf. Looking at the font in Acrobat Reader it says font `F30` type 3 not embedded. I'm using MiKTeX 4.0.1.

Is there any other font (preferably lmodern) which includes these symbols as vector symbols?

```
\documentclass [] {article}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
    \mars%
    \female%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite likely you don't have installed the Type1 version of `wasysym`, see https://miktex.org/packages/wasy-type1 or have not updated the font maps.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, this solved the problem, the package wasn't installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The “complete” `wasy` fonts consist of three different CTAN packages:

https://ctan.org/pkg/wasy
https://ctan.org/pkg/wasysym
https://ctan.org/pkg/wasy-type1

The first one provides the Metafont sources for the fonts and basic support for plain TeX (with `wasyfont.tex`).

The second one provides LaTeX support for the fonts (with `wasysym.sty` and related `.fd` files).

The third one provides the Type1 (scalable) version of the fonts.

Unless you install the last one, the fonts will be bitmaps. The reason for the separation is that the three packages are by different people.

Answer (score 7):

Try a different package, in this case, `marvosym`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
    A\Male%
    \Female%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok that worked, although they are quite bold. I wonder how the author of this document [link](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) has managed it to get the biological symbols (see page 131) out of the `wasysym` package as vector font.

Comment: OK egreg solved my initial problem with `wasysym` font. Also thank you for your answer that package is also nice.

Answer (score 1):

With `fontspec`, you can load them from any Unicode font that contains them, such as

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand\Male{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2642}}}
\newcommand\Female{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2640}}}
```

You could set the ♀ and ♂ Unicode characters active with `newunicodechar`.